# generating tabs and tables within multiple while loop

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to generate Tabs from 1st while loop and within that table from second while loop.

I will fetch the records date wise from my 1st table ie, `treatment` from that i am generating Tab, In another table called `treatment_litems` i have stored all the line items for treatment table records. So for 1st date (Tab) from treatment table, i want to display all the related records from treatment_litems in table format.

I am getting records but Tabs are not getting added, but everytime new Tabs are generating.

here is  my code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <?php $i=1; while($tt2 = mysqli_fetch_array($tt1)) { ?>

      <li>
         <a href="#tab_1_<?php echo $i; ?>" data-toggle="tab"> <?php echo $tt2['date']; ?> </a>
      </li>

       </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab_1_<?php echo $i; ?>">
          <?php $l1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM treatment_litems WHERE tid=".$tt2['tid'].""); ?>
             <table class="table">
                <thead><tr><th>Drugs</th><th>Route</th><th>Dosage</th></tr></thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <?php
                        while($l2 = mysqli_fetch_array($l1)) { ?>

                 <tr><td><?php echo $l2['drugs']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $l2['route']; ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo $l2['dosage']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                   <?php } ?>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
                 <?php $i++ ; } ?>
                    </div>
```

Here is the image
[image: tabs]

**** EDITED ******

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                        <?php  
                                        while($tt2 = mysqli_fetch_array($tt1)) { ?>

                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="#tab_1_<?php echo $tt2['tid']; ?>" data-toggle="tab"> <?php echo $tt2['date']; ?> </a>
                                                </li>


                                            </ul>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <div class="tab-content">
                                                <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab_1_<?php echo $tt2['tid']; ?>">
```

Comment: Can you show your response image?

Comment: i have added the images

Comment: Your tab jquery code?

Comment: @jyoti: I dont think its because of jquery, its because of loop. As i am using the same jquery for other pages also

Comment: Okay. then you need to add two while loop for ul and li both, as ul starting out of while loop and closing inside. to make id same you can use table primary key instead of $i. Please try and let me knwo.

Comment: I have edited my code above, i thik i am doing it wrongly :(. Can you please review my code?

Comment: Have you checked my code?

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code, you can get hints by this:

```
  <div id="tabs" style="float:left">
      <ul>
           <?php  $getlang=mysql_query("select * from language where Mid='$mid' and status='1' order by LanguageName asc");
    if(mysql_num_rows($getlang)>0){
      while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($getlang)){?>
                <li><a href="#tabs-<?php echo $arr['LanguageID'] ?>"><?php echo $arr['LanguageName']; ?></a></li>
                <?php }}?>

              </ul>

<?php $getlang=mysql_query("select * from language where Mid='$mid' and status='1' order by LanguageName asc");
    if(mysql_num_rows($getlang)>0){
      while($arr=mysql_fetch_array($getlang)){?>

              <div id="tabs-<?php echo $arr['LanguageID'] ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="LanguageId[]" class="langID" value="<?php echo $arr['LanguageID']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="mid" value="<?php echo $mid; ?>">
               <div class="rows">
                    <label>Notification Text</label><br/>
                    <textarea rows="3" cols="10" name="description[]" id=""  maxlength="1000" style="width:700px; height:100px;" required="required"></textarea>

                  </div>
              </div>
<?php } }
```

Check and do let me know.

Comment: No use :(. Trying it out